# WebBrowser Control in ASP.NET Web Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webbrowser-control

Scenario: 
I'd like to use a WebBrowser Control to proxy website navigation on external websites for a research project. Therefore I tried to use the WebBrowser Control to load the site within a page request and forward the received HTML with some modifications (as changed src/href and javascript event handlers aso.). When a participant/user triggers an onclick event on the proxied website, I fetch this event on the server and would like to re-trigger it within my WebBrowser Control.

Problem:
I can't figure out how to handle the WebBrowser Control. Initially I thought it is just the matter of storing it as a session object, but the fact that it has to run in an STA thread makes this difficult. I need the same, active, browser object when the user invokes an onclick event to allow me to proxy this onclick on the control.
For now I use a Wrapper Class IEBrowser: System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext.
I copied the code from different sources, mainly from (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET) but it does not consider using the same WebBrowser Control over many Requests.
Here is some of the code from the IEBrowser class:

```
public void Nav(string url)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.resultEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    htmlResult = null;
    ths = new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        // create a WebBrowser control
        ieBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        //Reset Session
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        // set WebBrowser event handls
        ieBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(IEBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        //make request
        ieBrowser.Navigate(url);

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(this);
        //remove WebBrowser event handler
        ieBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(IEBrowser_DocumentIsCompleted);
        //for now, we keep the webBrowser open
        //ieBrowser.Dispose();
    });
    thrd = new Thread(ths);
    thrd.Name = "Thread 2";
    thrd.IsBackground = true;
    // set thread to STA state before starting
    thrd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thrd.Start();
    EventWaitHandle.WaitAll(new AutoResetEvent[] { resultEvent });
    thrd.Join();
}

// DocumentCompleted event handle
void IEBrowser_DocumentIsCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ieBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && ieBrowser.IsBusy == false)
    {
        //Replace or Set IDs on every HTML Element [...]
        //...
        //
        ieBrowser.Stop();
        ExitThread();
        //Dispose();
        resultEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Limitations:
This is not about performance, I need to do this remote, but only 1-5 person will use the site simultaniously. I know that using WebBrowser Control is probably not a good solution in general, but in this case it is exactly what I need to capture all user navigation.

Comment: Are you trying to use the WebBrowser in a server process?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes. Is there a way to save the browser and reload it on next post back? Maybe serialization or saving sessions and browser data?

Comment: I don't know if it'd suit what you're doing, but depending on the page, would you be able to invoke a script within the page to re-trigger the event?  If so, you could use something like ieBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("triggerEvent"); where "triggerEvent" is the name of the function you want to call to replicate the event.

Comment: @RobWilkins no need for that. I need to keep a browser alive for parsing it, showing detail to user on the webpage, allowing them to make choices, then going back to the browser control and invoke those actions. So must keep it alive between postbacks.